# Formatação de data nativa do JavaScript não funciona

Tags: javascript

Tenho um modal preenchido via JavaScript. O código JavaScript é o seguinte:

```js
// INTERFACE MODAL viewVenda
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if (id !== '') {
            var dados = {
                id: id
            };
            $.post('dsVenda.php', dados, function (retorna) {
                var venda = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
                venda = retorna.split(',');
                $("#var0").html(venda[0]);
                $("#var1").html(venda[1]);
                $("#var2").html(venda[2]);
                $("#var3").html(venda[3]);
                $("#var4").html(venda[4]);
                $("#var5").html(venda[5]);
                var data = venda[6];
                data_formatada = data.toLocaleDateString('pt-br');
                $("#var6").html(data_formatada);
                $("#var7").html(venda[7]);
                $("#var8").html(venda[8]);
                $("#var9").html(venda[9]);
                $('#viewVenda').modal('show');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

A variável contida em **venda[6]** tem o valor **2020-03-06 15:11:15** cadastrado no banco de dados.

Estou formatando via função nativa do JavaScript para o padrão Brasil dd/MM/yyyy mas o modal não abre. Se eu mostrar o valor bruto da seguinte forma ele abre.

```js
$("#var6").html(venda[6]);
```

O mesmo problema acontece se eu tentar formatar  valor venda[3] e venda[5] que são valores monetários

Comment: Só um detalhe, se quer forçar sempre o formato brasileiro, passe o *locale* como parâmetro: `data.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')` - caso contrário ele pegará o locale que estiver configurado no browser, e nem sempre é garantido que seja `pt-BR` - ex: https://repl.it/repls/SandyOvercookedAlgorithm - De qualquer forma, onde está o modal? Dá algum erro (e se dá, qual é a mensagem)? `venda[6]` é uma string no formato "2020-03-06 15:11:15" ou é um `Date`? (não dá para testar esse código sem saber dessas informações, e **talvez** seja por isso que a pergunta esteja recebendo votos negativos)

Comment: O erro é que o `toLocaleDateString` só funciona com objeto `Date`. Por causa do erro o script para de executar.

Comment: venda[] é um vetor. pego a posição [6] dele.

Comment: Sim, mas a posição 6 tem uma string, um `Date`, ou o que? Se ele não tem um `Date`, então o problema é o que o Sam falou acima. Se ele tiver um `Date`, então o problema deve estar em outro lugar, etc.. Percebe como não tem como a gente testar e só com as informações da pergunta a única opção é tentar adivinhar? Isso pode explicar os votos negativos... Por favor clique em [edit] e coloque as informações necessárias para que qualquer um possa testar (sugiro que leia como montar um **[mcve]** <<< aqui tem várias dicas para montar um exemplo adequado)

Comment: `var data = venda[6];` é uma string, você está tentando utilizar o método `toLocaleDateString` que é do objeto Date, conforme o @Sam falou. Você pode usar `"2020-03-06 15:11:15".replace(/(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})(.*)/, "$3/$2/$1");` no lugar.

Comment: @Benilson deu certo com o campo tipo data. Tentei fazer uma REGEX para usar com campos do tipo monetário mas não deu certo, como seria para formatar tipo R$ 32.000,00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez isso te ajude:

```js
var data = new Date();
data.toLocaleDateString('pt-br');
var hora = data.getHours();
var minuto = data.getMinutes();
var segundos = data.getSeconds();
var dia = data.getDate();
var mes = data.getMonth() + 1;
var ano = data.getFullYear();

console.log(`Hoje é exatamente ${dia}/${mes}/${ano}`)
console.log(`São exatamente: ${hora}:${minuto}:${segundos}`)
```

Uma outra alternativa é utilizar o momenjs:

rode o comando:
`npm install moment` no prompt de comando e dentro do diretório do projeto

e depois configure o arquivo assim:

```
const moment = require('moment');

moment(/*se tiver variável de data passe aqui*/).locale('pt-br').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: Pra que chamar `toLocaleDateString` se vc não usa o retorno dela pra nada? Outro detalhe é que `toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')` retorna os valores com zero à esquerda caso necessário (ex: 17/03/2020) e o seu código não trata isso (retorna 17/3/2020). De qualquer forma, a pergunta não parece ser exatamente "*como formatar data*" e sim "*o modal não abre quando uso esse código*" (embora não tenha ficado claro que modal é esse e qual erro ocorre, mas de qq forma, o problema parece ter relação com esse modal, e não com a formatação em si)

Comment: Amigo só respondi oq tá na pergunta do título, então a pergunta tem que ser melhorada, e obrigado pela dica

Comment: O que deve ser respondido é o problema que está sendo descrito no corpo da pergunta. Se a pergunta não está clara e/ou não corresponde ao título, então o melhor é pedir esclarecimentos ao autor e só responder depois que ele melhorar a pergunta.